# Android design support library proguard rules

Tags: android, proguard, androiddesignsupport, android-proguard

Have been trying to find some information about the rules needed for the new design support library to work passing proguard. I couldn't find any information about it.

Ended up using these rules:

```
-keep class android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
```

These rules seem to work but I'm not really sure if there are better rules or if it works with all the classes inside the design support library

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I meet this error `error while parsing android/support/design/R$anim.class`.

End it with this code:

```
# support design
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }
```

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
-keep public class * extends android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
```